# I want Generic class's "Class<T>" with "Class variable"

Tags: java, class

I want to get Generic class's type variable for JsonDeserialize.

```
Class Data<T> {
  private T data;
}

Class DataType {
  private String dummy;
}


Class dataTypeClass = DataType.class;


// I want get this.
Class dataClass = Data<dataTypeClass>.class;
```

I've tried it like this way, It doesn't work.

Could I get Data.class ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get generic type of class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime)

Comment: What library are you using? Jackson?

Comment: @Lino yes. I used Jacksion

Comment: That's interesting. I could solve the problem in a hacky way that I wouldn't share with someone who wouldn't understand it, but I couldn't find anything where jackson helps with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Jackson as your library. You can just use [`TypeReference`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html):

```
TypeReference<Data<DataType>> r = new TypeReference<Data<DataType>>() {};
...
Data<DataType> data = objectMapper.readValue(json, r);
```

This code will create a new anonymous sub class of `TypeReference` parameterized with `<Data<DataType>>`. This class internally uses a "hackaround" to get the generic parameter, which then is picked up by Jackson to deserialize your JSON.

Comment: Could i get TypeReference from `Class variable` ??

Comment: @LKC then you can just call `objectMapper.readValue(json, variable)` if you already have a `Class`